# Solve initial value two-dimensional heat equation inside a circle $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \, \nabla^2 u$ with $u(a, \theta, t) = g(\theta)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

> Q: Solve the initial value problem for a two-dimensional heat equation inside a circle (of radius $a$) with time-independent boundary conditions:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= k \,\nabla^2 u \\
>   u(a, \theta, t) &= g(\theta) \\
>   u(r, \theta, 0) &= f(r, \theta) \\
> \end{align*}

I'm pretty sure that the first step is to transform this problem into a problem with homogeneous boundary conditions. I can do that. I'm having problems solving it from there, however.

*EDIT*: Fixed the equilibrium solution.

Identify equilibrium solution (omitting the steps):

\begin{align*}
  \nabla^2 u_E(r, \theta) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  u_E(r,\theta) &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A_n r^n \cos (n \theta) + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n r^n \sin (n \theta) \\
\end{align*}

Then we use the orthogonality equations to solve for the coefficients:

\begin{align*}
  A_0 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(\theta) \, d\theta \\
  A_{n\ge 1} &= \frac{1}{\pi a^n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(\theta) \cos (n \theta) \, d\theta \\
  B_{n \ge 1} &= \frac{1}{\pi a^n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(\theta) \sin (n \theta) \, d\theta \\
\end{align*}

Transform to displacement problem with homogeneous boundary conditions:

\begin{align*}
  v(r, \theta, t) &= u(r, \theta, t) - u_E(r, \theta) \\
  u(r, \theta, t) &= v(r, \theta, t) + u_E(r, \theta) \\
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= k \, \nabla^2 v \\
  v(a, \theta, t) &= 0 \\
  v(r, \theta, 0) &= f(r, \theta) - u_E(r, \theta) \\
\end{align*}

Solve the homogeneous displacement problem.

Periodicity:

\begin{align*}
  v(r, \pi, t) &= v(r, -\pi, t) \\
  \frac{dv}{d\theta}(r, \pi, t) &= \frac{dv}{d\theta}(r, -\pi, t) \\
\end{align*}

Separate:

\begin{align*}
  v(r, \theta, t) &= w(r, \theta) h(t) \\
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= k \,\nabla^2 v \\  
  \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{h} \frac{dh}{dt} &= \frac{1}{w} \, \nabla^2 w = -\lambda \\
  w(a, \theta) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

separate again:

\begin{align*}
  w(r, \theta) &= \phi(\theta)G(r) \\
  G(a) &= 0 \\
  \nabla^2 w &= -\lambda w \\
  \nabla^2 w &= \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta^2} = -\lambda w \\
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{1}{G} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \frac{dG}{dr} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{1}{\phi} \frac{d^2 \phi}{d\theta^2} &= -\lambda \\  
  \frac{1}{r} \frac{1}{G} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \frac{dG}{dr} \right) &= -\lambda - \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{1}{\phi} \frac{d^2 \phi}{d\theta^2} = -\mu \\  
%  \nabla^2 w &= \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \theta^2} &= -\lambda w \\
%  \frac{1}{G} \frac{d^2 G}{dr^2} + \frac{1}{G} \frac{1}{r} \frac{dG}{dr} + \frac{1}{\phi} \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d^2 \phi}{d\theta^2} &= -\lambda \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \frac{dG}{dr} \right) &= -\mu rG \\
\end{align*}

I'm not sure what to do next and I suspect I didn't take the right route. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your $u_E$ correct? it seems that it is not differentiable at the origin (when $r=0$).

Comment: $\frac{\partial u_E}{\partial r}(r,\theta) = \frac{g(\theta)}{a}$. That seems differentiable at the origin. Explain.

Comment: Note that $\nabla^2 u_E \neq 0$ if $u_E$ is continuous, unless $g$ is constant. Consequently if $u(r,\theta,t)=u_E(r,\theta)+v(r,\theta,t)$ then you get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=\nabla^2 u=\nabla^2 u_E + \nabla^2 v$, which is now an inhomogeneous diffusion equation (with forcing constant in time) but with homogeneous boundary data.

Comment: Alternately you can try to actually find an equilibrium solution with the appropriate boundary data by using the Green's function for the disk.

Comment: $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so for example $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: You are both right that the equilibrium solution is not right. How do I get the right equilibrium solution? And what do I do after I get that and convert the boundary conditions to homogeneous? @Ian, can you elaborate on your suggestion of using Green's function?

Comment: The Green's function is essentially the same thing as the Poisson kernel: that is, you can solve the Laplace equation on the disk with Dirichlet boundary data by convolving against the Poisson kernel. See for example the very end of http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~sijue/greensfunction.pdf (This formula can also be obtained by separation of variables.) Now if you write $u$ as the solution to the corresponding Laplace equation plus an unknown function $v(x,y,t)$, then you are left to solve the ordinary heat equation with homogeneous boundary data.

Comment: Of course it might be more useful to do separation of variables in the first place instead, so that the solution to the corresponding Laplace equation gets written as a Fourier series. Then you can solve the heat equation that you need to solve by just expanding $f$ into Fourier series and then subtracting off the Fourier series of $u_E$.

Comment: I fixed the equilibrium solution. I'm still stuck on the time-dependent problem with homogeneous (Dirichlet) boundary conditions. @ian, I will study that link. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of variables gives eigenfunctions of the Laplacian $\phi_n(r,\theta)=r^{|n|} e^{in\theta}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Expanding $g$ in a Fourier series $\sum c_n e^{in\theta}$, you then have that $u_E(r,\theta)=\sum a^{-|n|} c_n \phi_n(r,\theta)$ is a steady state solution. You can now reduce the desired heat equation to one with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions by subtracting off this steady state from the initial condition, i.e. you are left to solve

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=k \nabla^2 v \\
v(a,\theta,t)=0 \\
v(r,\theta,0)=f(r,\theta) - u_E(r,\theta).$$

This can again be done by separation of variables; if $f(r,\theta)=\sum b_n \phi_n(r,\theta)$ then the initial condition is now $\sum (b_n - a^{-|n|} c_n) \phi_n(r,\theta)$ and now you can solve the heat equation when the initial condition is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian and then apply superposition. Solving the heat equation when the initial condition, say $h$, is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian is very simple: if $h$ is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian which corresponds to the boundary condition and with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the heat equation will just give you $v=e^{\lambda k t} h$. Here the eigenvalues are $-n^2$, so you end up with

$$u(r,\theta,t)=\sum a^{-|n|} c_n \phi_n(r,\theta) + \sum e^{-n^2 kt}(b_n-
 a^{-|n|} c_n) \phi_n(r,\theta).$$

Note that one must have $\lim_{r \to a^-} f(r,\theta)=g(\theta)$ for this to all make sense.